# What use do these round pads have on PCB?

Tags: pcb, pins, pad

I always find these pads on boards:

[image]

What use do they have? Is there a specific connector for them or do you need to solder a wire on them?

Comment: The TP designation means that they are test points, intended for use with probes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Probably they connect to a "bed of nails" test equipment.

TP1, TP2 and two other circular pads (that appear to be referenced TP_something) are "test points" and if this circuit board is a medium to high volume then it's likely that the test points make contact with test equipment during manufacture to inject (or measure) certain voltages in order to determine that the correct components have been fitted.

[image]

[image]

The two thru-hole plated pads might be fixing a 0.1" 2 pin connector with the square pad being normally regarded as pin 1 (a polarity guide).