# PCB Chip cover?

Tags: pcb, integrated-circuit

I have been in electronics as a hobbyist in the past year and a half but still I come across some new things everyday. I have two questions regarding a pcb of a device that I have taken apart (picture below):

1.) Is that some sort of cover/paste for the main chip of the pcb? I have seen this thing in many circuits now (black, white) and I am curious what it is - I guess this is not the shape of the chip itself?

2.) What is the purpose of those copper "circles"? They are not vias since they don't have any holes.

[image]

Thank you for your answers in advance!

EDIT: Thanks for the attached links/replies. If someone is interested in the manufacturing process of these chip-on-boards, here is a link that I found: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-chip-on-boards-are-made

Comment: The copper circles are usually test points for automated test, manual test or debugging of notable traces in the circuit.

Comment: Your first question is answered here: [What kind of components are black blobs on a PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9137/)

Comment: The second one is answered here: [What use do these round pads have on PCB?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/173068/)